# Генерации последовательных чисел из указанного диапазона

Tags: php

Всем привет, помогите примером скрипта генерации последовательных чисел из указанного диапазона с повторением одного числа n-ое кол-во раз в столбик.

```
704
704
704
705
705
705
```

и т.д.

**Из комментариев:**

Я сейчас в цмс опенкарт подготавливаю файл для массового импорта товаров с одинаковыми атрибутами, ценами и т.д. В опенкарте таблицы Опций вынесены в отдельную составляющую.

Желаемый результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: Если не сложно, расшифруйте фразу "с повторением одного числа n-ое кол-во раз в столбик"? Было бы отлично, если вы привели бы какой результат вы ожидаете увидеть.

Comment: Диапазон для генерации от 704 и до 804. Число 704 должно генерироваться(повторяться) 10 раз, после чего идет следующее число 705, оно так же генерируется 10 раз, потом следующее и так пока не дойдет до 804.

Comment: от а до b, n повторений. и что дальше? вы не можете два цикла написать - по диапазону и от 0 до n-1 ? вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: все, мне это для подготовки файла импорта с опциями товаров. Благодарю, да, не могу, а точнее не умею.

Comment: тогда хотя бы покажите желаемый результат.

Comment: https://psv4.vk.me/c615428/u311119692/docs/1918ffa57a4d/123.jpg?extra=tzJ0N-ckP_KK7bFL1MdXTy3C_XQlIbIw70qtHevuyLqzoE4yZ-A86jidW5RHLCY7q5AbPRPiDithP9n6ikZdA-1kfhKCdCcn1TVuLksU-AL6Bvra_FHrJyXadC4S

Comment: страница не найдена :) такое и вы сможете

Comment: я эти сгенерированные числа вставлю в столбец

Comment: http://pastenow.ru/NKK7

Comment: мне кажется вы неправильно проблему излагаете. Вам что надо в результате  - csv файл? веб страничку?

Comment: нет, я сейчас в цмс опенкарт подговаливаю файл для массового импорта товаров с одинаковыми атрибутами, ценами и т.д. В опенкарте таблицы Опций вынесены в отдельную составляющую. Поэтому такой гемр

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такие задачи решаются циклом.

`a` - **начало отрезка**, `b` - **конец отрезка**, `n` - **количество повторений**

```
for ($i = $a; $i <= $b; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j<$n; $j++)
    echo "$i \n";
}
```

**Код основан на беглом прочтении мануала по пхп**

Comment: $a=704, $b=804, $i=10? да, но я так и не врубился за несколько часов

Comment: @идентикон что ты не понял? разберемся

Comment: а как echo в txt с /n сделать?

Comment: в целом нет, я бы уже в целом был благодарен за код, 100 вкладок открыто, а толку нет

Comment: @идентикон кинь полностью код

Comment: `код
$a=704;
$b=706;
$n=2;
for ($i = $a; $i <= $b; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j<$n; $j++)
    echo $i n/;
}
`

Comment: @идентикон http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12fc762ce8d099626c1c4db314a0fc8b7131ebc9 - вроде работает, ИЛИ ТЕБЕ НУЖНО ЧТО-ТО ДРУГОЕ?

Comment: ага, я с строкой не могу придумать, чтобы переносились

Comment: @идентикон обновил ответ

Comment: мужик!!! Дай бог тебе здоровья и светлых мыслей!